# How to determine if a user is using "find" in a program like Adobe Acrobat

Tags: c++

I am lost in how to even research this query. I have tried all the variations of the question that I can think of in Google.

Basically I am looking into creating a program that can be run on a computer that can watch a users activities, such as using the find feature in adobe acrobat or reader.

Why I am looking into this:

I presently a student and take all my notes on a MS Surface Pro 3.

When we have open book exams or quizzes, prof's do not allow electronic devices since they cannot control a student just using the "find" in a textbook pdf to find their answers.

This results in having to print all my notes to paper, and is a hassle.

Having an application that could log a users use of their computer for a given time range, then perhaps emailing the results to a professor (or something like that) could potentially provide a solution to this problem.

Thanks for any help and direction. I wish I could ask the question a little clearer.

SUB

Comment: Do you really think any professor would trust a student's device is properly secured by something like that...?  They might as well trust you not to do it in the first place.  I think you're wasting your time.  Buy texts with decent indices / tables of contents....

Comment: Try a tool such as [WinSpy++][1] to learn the window hierarchy of Adobe. The search box has most probably got some unique window handle name. Once you found it, you could write a software that polls Adobe's window hierarchy to detect that specific search box. The other harder part is, as @TonyD suggested, how does your teacher trust that you simply don't turn off the detection software?


  [1]: http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This will go a way into how to research this topic. Regarding a prof not trusting a student application... I only want to present a complete concept to my prof's that may take it towards coming up with something that can make everyone happy. This is a hole that needs filling.